# Logstash timestamp issue - the parsed value is one hour behind the log value

Tags: timestamp, logstash, timezone-offset

I am using the following code to read McAfee Logs  ( I chose to use CSV filters because grok filters turned out to be messy)

```
input {

 stdin{}
}

filter {

csv {
         columns => ["timestamp", "McAf_ThreatSeverity", "McAf_Event", "McAf_EventDescription", "McAf_EventCategory", "McAf_ThreatT$

          separator => "|"
    }


date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["timestamp", "dd/MM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss"]
        timezone => "Europe/London"
        add_tag => "McAfee_ThreatEventLog"
   }

  }

output {
    elasticsearch {
       #action => "index"
        host => "localhost"
        }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
     }
}
```

The input is something like this ...

```
31/03/2015:12:59:07| SEVERITY_CRITICAL | 1093| Buffer Overflow detected and blocked| Host intrusion buffer overflow| 10.3.1.252| Blocked| buffer overflow
```

The output is ok EXCEPT for the timestamp which is one hour behind that in the logs. That is,

```
Using milestone 2 filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
31/03/2015:12:59:07| SEVERITY_CRITICAL | 1093| Buffer Overflow detected and blocked| Host intrusion buffer overflow| 10.3.1.252| Blocked| buffer overflow
{
                         "message" => [
        [0] "31/03/2015:12:59:07| SEVERITY_CRITICAL | 1093| Buffer Overflow detected and blocked| Host intrusion buffer overflow| 10.3.1.252| Blocked| buffer overflow"
    ],
                        "@version" => "1",
                      "@timestamp" => "2015-03-31T11:59:07.000Z",
                            "host" => "UOD-220076",
                       "timestamp" => "31/03/2015:12:59:07",
             "McAf_ThreatSeverity" => " SEVERITY_CRITICAL ",
                      "McAf_Event" => " 1093",
           "McAf_EventDescription" => " Buffer Overflow detected and blocked",
              "McAf_EventCategory" => " Host intrusion buffer overflow",
    "McAf_ThreatTargetIPv4Address" => " 10.3.1.252",
                "McAf_ActionTaken" => " Blocked",
                 "McAf_ThreatType" => " buffer overflow",
                            "tags" => [
        [0] "McAfee_ThreatEventLog"
    ]
}
```

In the output above, the time in the log is 12:59:07 but the parsed value is 11:59:07.

The interesting thing is that I parsed different logs yesterday (firewall logs) using the following code:

```
input {

 stdin{}
}

filter {

csv {
         columns => ["timestamp", "Interface", "Origin", "Type", "Action", "Service", "SourcePort", "SourceIP", "DestinationIP", "P$
         separator => "|"
    }


date {
        locale => "en"
        match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss"]
        timezone => "Europe/London"
        add_tag => "checkpoint_fw"

   }


}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost"
        }
    stdout {
```

And the following input....

18/MAR/2015:15:00:00| eth3-04| grog1| Log| Accept| http| 46718| 193.60.148.101| 23.194.230.180| tcp| 0| | | inzone: Local; outzone: External; service_id: http; message_info: Implied rule| Security Gateway/Management

Which gives the correct output of the timestamp as shown below:

```
    [0] "18/MAR/2015:15:00:00| eth3-04| grog1| Log| Accept| http| 46718| 193.60.148.101| 23.194.230.180| tcp| 0| | | inzone: Local; outzone: External; service_id: http; message_info: Implied rule| Security Gateway/Management"
],
     "@version" => "1",
   "@timestamp" => "2015-03-18T15:00:00.000Z",
         "host" => "UOD-220076",
    "timestamp" => "18/MAR/2015:15:00:00",
    "Interface" => " eth3-04",
       "Origin" => " grog1",
         "Type" => " Log",
       "Action" => " Accept",
      "Service" => " http",
   "SourcePort" => " 46718",
     "SourceIP" => " 193.60.148.101",
"DestinationIP" => " 23.194.230.180",
     "Protocol" => " tcp",
         "Rule" => " 0",
     "RuleName" => " ",
  "CurrentRule" => " ",
  "Information" => " inzone: Local; outzone: External; service_id: http; message_info: Implied rule",
      "Product" => " Security Gateway/Management",
         "tags" => [
    [0] "checkpoint_fw"
```

The only difference between the McAfee script and the firewall script (apart from the fields obviously) is that the firewall script uses dd/MMM/YYYY whilst the McAfee script uses dd/MM/YYYY - I highly doubt that would be a significant difference.

Any ideas anyone on how I can get the McAfee timestamp to be exactly what's on the logs ? ( I have even tried changing timezones but all that has done is increase the time difference) - is there a way of saying " + 1 hour" in logstash (not kibana) ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. The Europe/London time zone is BST (GMT+100) starting March 29th. Your other entry was from the 18th which is prior to the BST mark.

Comment: Alcanzar you are right - I had thought of that. Thing is, I still want to solve this issue - I can't have the logs being 1 hour behind - I need the time exactly as it is on the logs - is there a way around ?

Comment: Elasticsearch stores all dates/times in GMT -- there's no getting around that... you can display them in whatever timezone you'd like in your UI or retain the non-parsed value in another field and display that (which you already do).